# How to resolve the error given below related to the file upload in google drive using Spring boot and postman?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file

**Error**

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Invalid mime type "media": does not contain '/']
```

This API is all about file operations in google drive using Spring boot rest API and here I am using postman for testing. While I am performing file upload I am getting the error given above. How to resolve it.

**Post request to upload file to the google drive**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload",
        consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} )
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadSingleFileExample4(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    //Log.info("Request contains, File: " + file.getOriginalFilename());
    String fileId = fileManager.uploadFile(file);
    if(fileId == null){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Success, FileId: "+ fileId);
}
```

**Method to perform upload operation**

```
  public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        //String folderId = getFolderId(filePath);
        if (file != null) {
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            //fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
            fileMetadata.setName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            File uploadFile = googleDriveManager.getInstance()
                    .files()
                    .create(fileMetadata, new InputStreamContent(
                            file.getContentType(),
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()))
                    )
                    .setFields("id").execute();
            return uploadFile.getId();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Error: "+e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image: Postman- file upload result]
Screenshot file upload

Comment: What does the "Headers" section contain in postman ?

Comment: Try to select files again in postman

Comment: Check if Content-Type is "multipart/formdata" in the Headers section in Postman.

Comment: @Rose getting an error like this the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found. In the header, I had added Content-Type as multipart/form-data and Accept as application/json. What exactly do we have added in the header to upload a multipart file and get a json response?

Comment: @Arnaud I had added  Content-Type as multipart/form-data and Accept as application/json. Now I am getting an error like this -  the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Comment: Just remove all the headers and try once

Comment: Try removing your custom Content-Type header, postman probably has an auto-generated one when you specify "form-data". You should be able to see the auto-generated headers by clicking on the "hidden" label from the Headers section.

Comment: Also replace @PostMapping(value = "/upload",
        consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} ) by @PostMapping("/upload")

Comment: @Rose by removing it i got response like this Success, FileId: 1TTbkR2qS6vkTf3KgL6zKXNI1jpPNXkjm.But this was in text format right.I want it in json

Comment: I think that's your fieldId, because you are returning " return ResponseEntity.ok("Success, FileId: "+ fileId);"

Comment: I mean you are returning a string. That's why you are getting that

Comment: @Rose So how do make it a JSON response, I  am using android for the front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You need to import,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

Use this to convert to JSON,

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

ObjectNode jsonObject = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
jsonObject.put("fileId", fileId);
jsonObject.put("message", "success");
return new ResponseEntity(jsonObject, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Change ResponseEntityofString to ResponseEntity